# How to set width to Input text field in bootstrap under class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the below layout, the last text field(UserName) alone not in correct size. I tried many ways, but nothing works. pls share any idea. my code is

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6  vcenter ">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                            <h4>Login Help</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <div class="row col-lg-12 radio">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd1" value="option1" checked>Forgot Username
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3" style="margin-top:2%;">
                                            <label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mail1" value="option1" checked>Email
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="form-group col-lg-offset-1">
                                            <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mob1" value="option1">Mobile
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="row col-lg-6">
                                            <label>Email Address</label>
                                            <!--<input class="col-lg-offset-1">-->
                                            <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                        </div>

                                    <div class="radio row col-lg-12" style="margin-top:5%;">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd2" value="option2">Forgot Password
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3" style="margin-top:2%;">
                                            <label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mail2" value="option1">Email
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="form-group col-lg-offset-1">
                                            <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mob2" value="option1">Mobile
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="row col-lg-6">
                                            <label>Email Address</label>
                                            <!--<input class="col-lg-offset-1">-->
                                            <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-12 row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">

                                                <label>Username</label>
                                                <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="Username" name="uname" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Torean The OP didn't indent their code, I've fixed it in an edit.

Comment: Did you want the text fields horizontally next to the lables or leave everything as is and just have the fields all the exact same (have the last field the same as the ones above it)?

Comment: Row and col-lg-12 are 100% width with appropriate margins and padding.  You shouldn't use both on one element.  Instead nest cols inside rows.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're concerned with is the size of the last input then change this:

You have `col-lg-12 row` with a `col-lg-6` inside of it, remove the `col-lg-6` and change the `col-lg-12 row` to `col-lg-6 row`.

That being said I've included two alternative layouts that use bootstrap default classes and standard layouts for [forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) that may help as you're mixing `col-*-*` with `rows` in the same `div` and that isn't how the grid is structured.

See working examples with your original code (*fixed) and two samples.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 row">
  <label>Username</label>
    <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="Username" name="uname" type="text">
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6  vcenter ">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
          <h4>Login Help (Original)</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row col-lg-12 radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd1" value="option1" checked>Forgot Username</label>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3" style="margin-top:2%;">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mail1" value="option1" checked>Email</label>
                  <label class="form-group col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mob1" value="option1">Mobile</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row col-lg-6">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <!--<input class="col-lg-offset-1">-->
                <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="radio row col-lg-12" style="margin-top:5%;">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd2" value="option2">Forgot Password</label>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3" style="margin-top:2%;">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mail2" value="option1">Email</label>
                  <label class="form-group col-lg-offset-1">
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mob2" value="option1">Mobile</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row col-lg-6">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <!--<input class="col-lg-offset-1">-->
                <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email">
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 row">

                <label>Username</label>
                <input class="form-control col-lg-offset-3" placeholder="Username" name="uname" type="text">

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 vcenter">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4>Standard Form</h4>

          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd1" value="option1" checked>Forgot Username</label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mail1" value="option1" checked>Email</label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mob1" value="option1">Mobile</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>Email Address</label>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd2" value="option2">Forgot Password</label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mail2" value="option1">Email</label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mob2" value="option1">Mobile</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>Email Address</label>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="uname" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 vcenter">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4>INLINE FORM</h4>

          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd1" value="option1" checked/>Forgot Username</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mail1" value="option1" checked/>Email</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="userMailMob" id="mob1" value="option1">Mobile</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Email Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="userPwd" id="userpwd2" value="option2" />Forgot Password</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mail2" value="option1" />Email</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="pwdMailMob" id="mob2" value="option1" />Mobile</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Email Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="uname" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Set the heights of input elements using classes like `.input-lg` and `.input-sm.`
>
> Set the widths of elements using grid column classes like `.col-lg-*` and `.col-sm-*`.

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)

Comment: Why not just reference [Bootstraps official site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: This was just a quick search, but I will change it.